# Remove port from NSURL

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsurl

How can one normalise an NSURL, removing the port in particular?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_normalization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write code to perform normalisation. `NSURL` may do some for you, but I don't think it's documented to do so.

Removing the port number won't necessarily work towards normalisation, but you can do it.

In both cases `NSURLComponents` will help you to by deconstructing the URL and allowing you to easily interact with each of the components parts, removing or modifying it as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in Wain's answer, `NSURLComponents` lets you deconstruct a URL and reconstruct a new URL with components you normalize. However, URL normalization is scheme specific (i.e. normalizing an http URL is very different than normalizing a file URL) and so you really have to know the syntax of the URL scheme you are working with.